# jquery uploadify, if empty

Tags: jquery, uploadify

is imposible with jquery uploadify check if empty, when i push upload button?
And if empty show error.

Thanks

EDIT: When user push button "Upload Files" without marking anything file system must show errors (you must select, or etc.)

If you don't understand my problem please look this:
http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/8854/erroruploadery.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited (x2):

Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var queueSize = 0;
function startUpload(){
    if (queueSize == 0) {
        alert("Please select a file first.");
    } else {
        $("#fileUpload").fileUploadStart();
    }
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#fileUpload").fileUpload({
    onCancel: function (a, b, c, d) {
        queueSize = d.fileCount;
    },
    onClearQueue: function (a, b) {
        queueSize = b.fileCount;
    },
    onSelectOnce: function (a, b) {
        queueSize = b.fileCount;
    },
    onAllComplete: function () {      
        queueSize = 0;
    },
    onComplete: function (a, b ,c, d, e) {
        queueSize = 0;
    },
});
</script>
```

Which you would call with:

```
startUpload();
```

Comment: Thanks for replay, but if file is empty function don't go in:
$("#fileInput2").uploadify({ 
 });

Comment: You mean if the file you are uploading is empty, that event doesn't fire? What error are you getting?

Comment: I mean, if i don't select any file and push button Upload Files. I wish see error.

Comment: Thank you, but I have now done so. I want when pressed send button without marking anything notified to report user (you must select, or etc. ). I hope to understand my problem

Comment: What I am saying is that you don't need a send button at all. Only a browse. Do you have a demo we could look at?

Comment: If you don't understand my problem please look this:
http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/8854/erroruploadery.png

Comment: Thank you very much ;). But i put in my code, and this don't work and i don't no way. if not very hard, maybe to show that the full sample. Thanks

Comment: I've been trying to help you now for ages, without so much as an up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

I did this in much simpler way. Add a div and associate it with uploadify 'queueId'

```
<asp:FileUpload name="fuFiles" ID="fuFiles" runat="server" />
                        <div id="fuItemsQueue" class="fuItemsQueue">
                        </div>

$("#<%=fuFiles.ClientID %>").uploadify({

                'swf': '../Scripts/uploadify.swf',
                'queueID': 'fuItemsQueue',
.....
            });
```

Just on the OnCancel Event just count the number of Divs left.

```
'onCancel': function () {

                    var queueCount = $("#fuItemsQueue > div").size();

                    if (queueCount = 1) {
                        DisableUploadButtons();
                    }
                }
```

And done!! :)